# update symfony 3.2.4 error via composer

Tags: php, symfony, composer-php

I have a symfony 3.2.4 project installed and configured, and everythings works fine.
Now I would like to update symfony version and relatives external bundles, and I typing on window platform:

```
php composer.phar update symfony/symfony
```

I obtain this error:

```
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.18 requires symfony/dependency-injection v2.0.18 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle v2.0.17 requires symfony/dependency-injection v2.0.17 -> no matching package found.
    - symfony/framework-bundle 2.0.7 requires symfony/translator 2.0.7 -> no matching package found.
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.8
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.7
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.6
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.5
    - Conclusion: remove symfony/symfony v3.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.4
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.3
    - Installation request for pinano/bootstrap3-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by pinano/bootstrap3-bundle[dev-master].
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.2
    - Conclusion: don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.1
    - pinano/bootstrap3-bundle dev-master requires symfony/framework-bundle 2.* -> satisfiable by symfony/framework-bundle[2.0.7, v2.0.10, v2.0.12, v2.0.13, v2.0.14, v2.0.15, v2.0.16, v2.0.17, v2.0.18, v2.0.19, v2.0.20, v2.0.21, v2.0.22, v2.0.23, v2.0.24, v2.0.25, v2.0.9, v2.1.0, v2.1.1, v2.1.10, v2.1.11, v2.1.12, v2.1.13, v2.1.2, v2.1.3, v2.1.4, v2.1.5, v2.1.6, v2.1.7, v2.1.8, v2.1.9, v2.2.0, v2.2.1, v2.2.10, v2.2.11, v2.2.2, v2.2.3, v2.2.4, v2.2.5, v2.2.6, v2.2.7, v2.2.8, v2.2.9, v2.3.0, v2.3.1, v2.3.10, v2.3.11, v2.3.12, v2.3.13, v2.3.14, v2.3.15, v2.3.16, v2.3.17, v2.3.18, v2.3.19, v2.3.2, v2.3.20, v2.3.21, v2.3.22, v2.3.23, v2.3.24, v2.3.25, v2.3.26, v2.3.27, v2.3.28, v2.3.29, v2.3.3, v2.3.30, v2.3.31, v2.3.32, v2.3.33, v2.3.34, v2.3.35, v2.3.36, v2.3.37, v2.3.38, v2.3.39, v2.3.4, v2.3.40, v2.3.41, v2.3.42, v2.3.5, v2.3.6, v2.3.7, v2.3.8, v2.3.9, v2.4.0, v2.4.1, v2.4.10, v2.4.2, v2.4.3, v2.4.4, v2.4.5, v2.4.6, v2.4.7, v2.4.8, v2.4.9, v2.5.0, v2.5.1, v2.5.10, v2.5.11, v2.5.12, v2.5.2, v2.5.3, v2.5.4, v2.5.5, v2.5.6, v2.5.7, v2.5.8, v2.5.9, v2.6.0, v2.6.1, v2.6.10, v2.6.11, v2.6.12, v2.6.13, v2.6.2, v2.6.3, v2.6.4, v2.6.5, v2.6.6, v2.6.7, v2.6.8, v2.6.9, v2.7.0, v2.7.1, v2.7.10, v2.7.11, v2.7.12, v2.7.13, v2.7.14, v2.7.15, v2.7.16, v2.7.17, v2.7.18, v2.7.19, v2.7.2, v2.7.20, v2.7.21, v2.7.22, v2.7.23, v2.7.24, v2.7.25, v2.7.26, v2.7.27, v2.7.3, v2.7.4, v2.7.5, v2.7.6, v2.7.7, v2.7.8, v2.7.9, v2.8.0, v2.8.1, v2.8.10, v2.8.11, v2.8.12, v2.8.13, v2.8.14, v2.8.15, v2.8.16, v2.8.17, v2.8.18, v2.8.19, v2.8.2, v2.8.20, v2.8.3, v2.8.4, v2.8.5, v2.8.6, v2.8.7, v2.8.8, v2.8.9].
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.0|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.1|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.10|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.11|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.12|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.13|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.14|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.15|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.16|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.17|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
    - don't install symfony/framework-bundle v2.7.18|don't install symfony/symfony v3.2.0
```

So, I've tried to update symfony installer via

```
php composer.phar self-update
```

and this is the response:

```
You are already using composer version 1.4.2 (stable channel).
```

Why I cannot update??

Below my composer.json

```
{
    "name" : "project",
    "license" : "proprietary",
    "type" : "project",
    "autoload" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "" : "src/"
        },
        "classmap" : [
            "app/AppKernel.php",
            "app/AppCache.php"
        ]
    },
    "autoload-dev" : {
        "psr-4" : {
            "Tests\\" : "tests/"
        }
    },
    "require" : {
        "php" : ">=5.5.9",
        "symfony/symfony" : "3.2.*",
        "doctrine/orm" : "^2.5",
        "doctrine/doctrine-bundle" : "^1.6",
        "doctrine/doctrine-cache-bundle" : "^1.2",
        "symfony/swiftmailer-bundle" : "^2.3",
        "symfony/monolog-bundle" : "^3.0",
        "symfony/polyfill-apcu" : "^1.0",
        "sensio/distribution-bundle" : "^5.0",
        "sensio/framework-extra-bundle" : "^3.0.2",
        "incenteev/composer-parameter-handler" : "^2.0",
        "friendsofsymfony/rest-bundle" : "^2.1",
        "jms/serializer-bundle" : "^1.1",
        "nelmio/cors-bundle" : "^1.4",
        "friendsofsymfony/user-bundle" : "~2.0@dev",
        "petkopara/crud-generator-bundle" : "^3.0",
        "twig/extensions" : "^1.4",
        "nelmio/api-doc-bundle" : "^2.13",
        "friendsofsymfony/oauth-server-bundle" : "^1.5",
        "creof/doctrine2-spatial" : "^1.1",
        "pinano/bootstrap3-bundle": "dev-master"
    },
    "require-dev" : {
        "sensio/generator-bundle" : "^3.0",
        "symfony/phpunit-bridge" : "^3.0"
    },
    "scripts" : {
        "post-install-cmd" : [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ],
        "post-update-cmd" : [
            "@symfony-scripts"
        ]
    },
    "extra" : {
        "symfony-app-dir" : "app",
        "symfony-bin-dir" : "bin",
        "symfony-var-dir" : "var",
        "symfony-web-dir" : "web",
        "symfony-tests-dir" : "tests",
        "symfony-assets-install" : "relative",
        "incenteev-parameters" : {
            "file" : "app/config/parameters.yml"
        }
    }
}
```

Thx in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The bundle "pinano/bootstrap3-bundle" is not compatible with Symfony 3

If you don't want integrate bootstrap manually, you can try braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle for example: https://packagist.org/packages/braincrafted/bootstrap-bundle